# Two jquery "on" events duplicates

Tags: jquery

I want to add a $(document).on('focusin'); only when the show.bs.popover is fired.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GrWzNg?editors=1111

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
$(document).on('show.bs.popover', function(e) {
  var popoverOpened = $(e.target);
  $(document).on('focusin', function(e) {
    popoverOpened.popover("hide");
  });
});
```

I also need to close the popover previously opened if I focus on another button.

You can see it here. The problem with this code is that it duplicated the console log after a few clicks of the buttons.

I want to be able to only fire the console.log once.

I don't want to add an event focus on everything if the even show.bs.popover is not fired...anyway to do this?

Comment: Better just add a class with one event handler and change the selector of the other

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what you are trying to accomplish here. When you show your popover, you are adding an event handler to try to hide your popover, which will get immediately triggered, because by clicking the button, you are focusing on the document.

Comment: Well what I am trying to accomplish is hiding the previously opened popover when I focus on another button

So if I open the first popover and I focus on the second button, the first popover should hide...var popoverOpened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit hard to help you because it isn't entirely sure what you are trying to accomplish. You are binding a focusin event to the complete document? It seems weird, because you are always focused on the document. Anyway, one thing you can tackle this problem is by checking if the popover has the class 'in'. Like so:

```
if($('.popover').hasClass('in')){
  console.log("hey");
}
```

The problem with this is it will be checked too early because you are checking at the moment the popover start event is fired. All together, I think you want to do this:

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover().on('mouseover', function(e) {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"],[data-original-title]').each(function() {
    if (!$(this).is(e.target)) {
      (($(this).popover('hide').data('bs.popover') || {}).inState || {}).click = false
    }
  });
});
```

The above code will open the popovers when you click a button, but will close all other open popovers when you hover another button.

Comment: this seems to be working, but can you explain this code :

    (($(this).popover('hide').data('bs.popover') || {}).inState || {}).click = false

Comment: Yes of course. First, we initiate te popover itself (you did that in your own code). With that, we open the popover on click. Then, by chaining, we bind a mouseover and on that mouseover it will loop through all the popovers and then it checks if the popover is the one that belongs to the button you clicked. If not, then it will close that popover.

Comment: All of this, I do not understand though 
.data('bs.popover') || {}).inState || {}).click = false

why do you do .data bs.popoover, what is inState and .click = false...I understand nothing of this..

Thank you by the way, it fixed my problem

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this instead.

Every time the `show.bs.popover` event was triggered, you were adding a duplicate event handler. Also, you were targeting the entire document for your `focusin` binding, not just the buttons, so your `focusin` binding would get triggered as soon as you click any button.

Just target your buttons with the selector `$('[data-toggle="popover"]')` the same way you were for displaying the popover in the first place, and tell all popovers to be hidden whenever you `mouseover` another button. Note that I used `mouseover` instead of `focusin`, as I believe this is what you meant to use. The `focusin` event would only be triggered when you <kbd>tab</kbd> from one button to the next, or actually click another button.

```js
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()

$('[data-toggle="popover"]').on('mouseover', function(e) {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover("hide");
});
```

```css
.container {
  margin-top:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">
  Popover on left
</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">
  Popover on top
</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="Vivamus
sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">
  Popover on bottom
</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">
  Popover on right
</button>
  
  </div>
```